# MySQL how to handle a value that changes with time, like price

Tags: mysql

I am building an events website and I need to store the price of an event. The price of an event will be updated with time. So the price is valid from the date it is entered to the date it is superseded. I need to keep the old prices to calculate accounts of events before the price change, so I cannot just update the price.

my events have different prices for event type, host club, age category, and if the rider is a member of the host club, therefore i have a "price" table with the columns:
`id_event_type  id_club  id_age_cat  club only (boolian, 1 for member of host club 0 for other)  price (float)  timestamp`

the "event" table has columns:
`id_event id_club id_event_type date`

I decided not to add a from and to date column as I would need to search to see if there is already an existing price for this combination and update the to-date (end date) and then create a new price with the current timestamp as the start date. but i could find the price by grouping all prices with the same price criteria and price start date before the event date and select the max date. This seems to be the easiest and most efficient way of storing the price. However, the query to get the price is quite complex. I am struggling to return just the row of data with the max date. i have a solution but it is overly complex

This is the query to get the list of prices for id_event = 5

```
`SELECT 
c.id_event,
c.id_age_cat,
c.id_club,
c.id_club_member.
d.price,
d.timestamp
from 
(select 
b.id_event,
a.id_club, 
a.id_age_cat, 
a.id_event_type, 
a.club_only,
if(a.club_only,a.id_club,NULL) as id_club_member,
max(a.timestamp) as new
from `price` a 
join `event` b on a.id_club = b.id_club
and a.id_event_type = b.id_event_type
where b.id_event =  5 
and b.date > a.timestamp
group by a.id_club, a.id_age_cat, a.id_event_type, a.club_only) c
join `price` d
on c.id_club= d.id_club 
and c.id_age_cat = d.id_age_cat
and c.id_event_type = d.id_event_type
and c.club_only = d.club_only
and c.new = d.timestamp`
```

This seems overly complicated. Is there a better way to do this?

I tried the following but got the wrong price. it returns dates that are less than the maximum:

```
`SELECT
a.id_age_cat,
if(a.club_only,a.id_club,NULL) as id_club_member,
a.price,
a.timestamp,
b.date
FROM `price` a
join `event` b on a.id_club = b.id_club
and a.id_event_type = b.id_event_type 
where b.id_event = 5
group by a.id_age_cat, a.club_only
having a.timestamp = max(a.timestamp)`
```

Comment: Tip - do not use `float` for price data.

Comment: In an e-commerce system I worked on, the current price was stored in an order at a certain point. So the history would be in the order, not (or as well as) in a separate price history. That would also make it easier to accomodate special cases, like customer-specific discounts. The order contained what the customer needed to pay, regardless (though normally based on) the current price. Maybe that could work here as well?

Comment: As this basically is unreadable (to some degree), and maintenance problems could come up, like not scaling with larger numbers, and then being unsure what indices and so on: **simplify**. Use concrete sample data. Remove `id_` from the column names, avoid `timestamp` as name. And no `float`. Ask a question with sample data, your query only as proof of effort.